# ldapsearch filter with numbers

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I have an LDAP with names formed as:
CN: First Middle Last 1234
where 1234 is the ID.
I want to search people by their full names like:
ldapsearch -o ldif-wrap=no -LLL -H ldaps://server -x "CN=First Middle Last *".
It is working in most of the cases but it happens that some people don't have middle name and the combination of "First Last *" could return entry of somebody with middle name == Last.
Can I define that "*" should match digits only?

Answer (score 1):

No. LDAP queries cannot be performed for only digits.

The ID should be stored in a proper attribute (uid or something similar).

You could perform the query and evaluate each result to determine if the middleName was a number.

-jim

Comment: It's not about ID but about full name which could collide when using "*".

Comment: Best Practices would use the a Unique Identifier for the "naming attribute" within LDAP that could never collide. Unfortunately, by default, Microsoft Active Directory chose to name by people names and not UniqueIDs which often leads to these collisions. You can however, name users by a UniqueID by setting the cn=uniqueID.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not up to me. I'm a user of the LDAP and have to work with what is already there.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but this is actually possible using the `<=` and `>=` comparisons, which will do a lexicographical comparison. That can be combined with wildcards:

```
(&(cn>=First Middle Last 0*)(cn<=First Middle Last 9*))
```

And if there's no middle name:

```
(&(cn>=First Last 0*)(cn<=First Last 9*))
```